# Compiler ignores code returning a local char* from a function

Tags: c++

As far as I know the following code is bad. But, Visual Studio 2010 doesn't give me any warning.

```
char* CEmployee::GetEmployeeName()
{
  char* szEmployeeName = "";
  CEmployeeModel* model = GetSwitchMod();
  if (model != NULL)
  {
    szEmployeeName = model->GetName();
  }

  return szEmployeeName; 
}
```

Comment: What documentation made you think Visual Studio 2010 would warn you about this?

Comment: This is a runtime problem, not a compile time. It is technically valid code until you try to access the pointer that is returned by GetEmployeeName().

Comment: @0A0D But what if `model->GetName();` returns a pointer to something whose lifespan exceeds that function call? Then `GetEmployeeName` is completely fine.

Comment: @Mark: Are you sure? He didn't allocate it onto the heap. I thought you had to use new[] and then assign.

Comment: @0A0D: Yes, and if `model->GetName()` does that, then there's no problem.

Comment: @0A0D We don't have the source for `GetName`. As far as we know it returns `new char[50]` or something.

Comment: @Mark: Interesting. On a side note, cppcheck does not complain about this code either.

Comment: @0A0D: Because it's not inherently invalid! It just _might_ invoke Undefined Behaviour, which cannot be diagnosed.

Comment: @Rob: It's not explicitly stated, though I'd suggest that it's easy enough to deduce.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the compiler's job to debug your code.

[lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm) or similar static checker might find this.  Try running [Code Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3bbz7tz.aspx) if you have one of the premium VS versions that includes it.  Make sure you build with [/W4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and fix all warning errors.

Answer (score 2):

Returning `szEmployeeName` here is actually not an error - the string is allocated statically in read-only memory (the `.rodata` section in ELF executables). Quoting the (C++03) Standard:

> **2.13.4.1**
>
> An ordinary string literal has type
>   “array of n const char” and **static
>   storage duration (3.7)**, where n is the
>   size of the string as defined below,
>   and is initialized with the given
>   characters.
>
> **3.7.1**
>
> All objects which neither have dynamic
>   storage duration nor are local have
>   static storage duration. **The storage
>   for these objects shall last for the
>   duration of the program**

On the other hand, trying to modify this string results in undefined behaviour - in this particular case, you'll most likely get a crash at runtime. `szEmployeeName` should be really declared as `const char*` (and there are historical reasons why the standard allows initializing a plain `char *` with a string literal). Again, quoting the Standard:

> **2.13.14.2**
>
> The effect of attempting to modify a
>   string literal is undefined.

Comment: Regarding your second statement... there are no historical reasons why it doesn't warn. It should. GCC does. Put some proper warning levels on. The reason it doesn't _error_ is that it's allowed, albeit deprecated. And trying to modify a `const` string can do more than crash your program: it can explode the universe, format your harddrive, or make demons fly out of your nose.

Comment: Better :) Though my remarks regarding your second statement still apply.

Comment: OK, now you should be satisfied :-)

Comment: I'm not entirely satisfied with "typically", which gives the wrong impression. And "historical" is still wrong: the reasons for not producing an error are current (namely, _it's not an error_). Better though!!

Comment: @Dennis Well, you have to store constant strings somewhere anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning a reference to a local variable, as you're returning by value, so the local variable — the pointer — is copied.

Don't confuse the pointer with its pointee.

If anything, you'd be returning a *dangling pointer* (though in practice the string literal buffer is likely to be in static memory somewhere). Dangling pointers don't tend to be diagnosed at compile-time.

*If* `model->GetName()` returns a dynamically-allocated buffer, making the pointer no longer point to the string literal, then your code is fine.

TRWTF is that you didn't write `char const* szEmployeeName = ""`. Leaving out the `const` has been deprecated for over a decade, and is illegal in C++0x. It's a concern that so many people are still doing this.

**It's even worse that there are still people using `char*` for strings, instead of `std::string`.**

Comment: Another one that boggles my mind is prefixing every class with `C`.

Comment: @MarkB: Ah yes; I think my brain managed to filter out that ghastly Hungarian notation somehow. :)

Comment: What if he did char const* szEmployeeName = new szEmployeeName[25]; would this still be valid if he returned it?

Comment: @0A0D: Yes, but why you'd use that instead of `std::string` is anybody's guess.

Comment: @Tomalak: Win32 ReadFile(..) in older implementations (that are still used) only take char *.

Comment: @0A0D: You should still maintain `std::string`s, and use `myString.c_str()` or `&myString[0]` when you need to pass a C-style buffer somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a pointer to a `char` at the end. Are you sure the memory that the pointer is referring to is still active when the code leaves the function* (what is the lifetime of `model->GetName()`'s return)

*EDIT: "loop" is wrong.

Comment: S/He knows that, Op needs to know why compiler didn't warn or some mechanism to warn him.

Comment: @TheCapn: To what "loop" are you referring?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I enabled Microsoft's code analysis tool and it didn't provide any warning related to this code and even when I wrote the code as bad as returning directly hard coded char* from my local variable of the function. Does anyone know any code analysis tool, which will provide this warning for sure?

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't necessarily "wrong" in all cases. If the thing pointed to by the pointer returned from `GetName` is still alive, and the pointer returned from `GetEmployeeName` is not written to then the code appears to be well-formed. The compiler can't reasonably be expected to do a full analysis of all your code to tell you if there's an actual problem with your pointer manipulation.

You should be using `std::string` as @Tomalak Geret'kal noted in his answer. That then resolves all these lifetime issues.

There's a certain point at which you should be able to say "Why am I writing code this way???" and the compiler isn't going to go to extra-ordinary lengths to warn you about every possible undefined behavior in your program (it's undefined for a reason).

Answer (score 0):

This code is fine.  There's nothing going on here that could possibly cause the target of `szEmployeeName` to be freed.

If `model` is `NULL`, then you return a pointer to `""`.  Using a non-const pointer certainly is questionable, but the string literal `""` survives for the lifetime of your program, it's not an error to return it.

If `model` is non-null, you return the pointer returned by `model->GetName()`.  Since `CEmployee::GetEmployeeName()` doesn't free any memory, the pointer is just as valid when returned as it was when you got it from `model->GetName()`.  Specifically, either the pointer is valid, or it is a dangling pointer, indicating a bug in `CEmployeeModel->GetName()`.

There are no circumstances where `CEmployeeModel::GetName()` is correct but `CEmployee::GetEmployeeName` returns a bad pointer.